# JavaFX Preloader Thread

Tags: javafx, preloader

I need someone explain me how Preloader works in JavaFX application. I have already found out the lifecycle and I know that first is called start(..) of preloader and then start(..) of Application but is this two methods are called from the same Thread? I have tried to make a simple app in start method of application a put Thread.sleep(8000) and in the start of Preloader I created a simple stage and show it. But when I run the application it just freeze with black stage and only after 8 seconds shows preloader stage correctly, but why?

*Update my post with source code:*

public class PreloaderApp extends Preloader {

```
public void init(){
    System.out.println("Thread Preloader ID:"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.out.println("  ------  ");

    Pane effectRegion = LoaderFrame.getInstance().getEffectPane();
    JFXFillTransition fill = new JFXFillTransition();
    fill.setDuration(Duration.millis(400));
    fill.setRegion(effectRegion);
    fill.setAutoReverse(true);
    fill.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    fill.setFromValue(Color.WHITE);
    fill.setToValue(Color.rgb(0,77,147));

    fill.play();

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    System.out.println("Thread Preloader(start) ID:"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.out.println("  ------  ");
    LoaderFrame.getInstance().show();

}
```

}

```
public class LoaderFrame extends Stage {
```

private static final LoaderFrame instance = new LoaderFrame();

```
public static LoaderFrame getInstance(){
    return instance;
}


private Scene scene;
private AnchorPane root;
private BorderPane wraper;
private StackPane effectPane;

private JFXButton loaderPathButton;


public LoaderFrame(){
    initScene();
    this.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    this.getIcons().add(new Image("file:imgs/favico/icon48.png"));
}

public void initScene(){
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("xml/loader_frame.fxml"));
    root = null;

    try {
        root = loader.load();
        wraper = (BorderPane) root.lookup("#rootPane");
        loaderPathButton = (JFXButton) root.lookup("#loaderPathButton");
        effectPane = (StackPane) root.lookup("#effectPane");
        scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("file:css/loader.css");
        this.setScene(scene);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public Pane getEffectPane(){
    return effectPane;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To investigate the `Preloader` lifecycle you could add the following line to your `Preloader` class:

```
    @Override
    public void handleStateChangeNotification(StateChangeNotification info) {
        System.out.println("state: " + info.getType());
    }
```

In your `Application` class you can add a `System.out.prinln` message in the `init` / `start` method. This will show the `Preloader` running through its different states: `BEFORE_LOAD`, `BEFORE_INIT`, `BEFORE_START`.

As the `Preloaders start method` is called on the `JavaFXThread` you have to wrap your call to `Thread.sleep` in `Platform.runlater`.

> Note that preloaders are subject to the same rules as other JavaFX applications including FX threading rules. In particular, the class constructor and init() method will be called on a non-FX thread and start() will be executed on the FX application thread. This also means that the application constructor/init() will run concurrently with preloader start().

If you need to do some time consuming initialization, you should do it in your Apps `init` method. When the `Preloader state` changes to `BEFORE_START` you can hide your `Preloader stage`

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static final int PRELOADER_SHOWTIME_MILLIS = 2000;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // time consuming initializations

        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        long remainingShowTime = PRELOADER_SHOWTIME_MILLIS - duration;

        if(remaingShowTime > 0 ){
            Thread.sleep(remainingShowTime);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane(new Label("application"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

public class TestPreloader extends Preloader {

    private Stage stage;  

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        stage = primaryStage;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200, 200, Color.RED);
        FadeTransition transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(2), rect);
        transition.setFromValue(0);
        transition.setToValue(1);

        Label lbl = new Label("preloader");
        StackPane root = new StackPane(rect, lbl);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        transition.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleStateChangeNotification(StateChangeNotification info) {
        if (info.getType() == Type.BEFORE_START) {
           stage.hide();
        }
     }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LauncherImpl.launchApplication(App.class, TestPreloader.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, I find out that preloader and Application are executed by the same thread. But supposing I have some animation, like javafx transition on preloader stage (start method) how can I keep live or execute that transition with another thread?

Comment: I suppose you want to show a splashscreen with an animation for a specific amount of time. If that's the case you could measure the time  spend in your `Application.init`, and call `Thread.sleep(remainingShowTime)` as last statement in `init`

Comment: Just to clarify: Your applications `start()` is running on the `JavaFXThread` just like `Preloader start()`. `Application init()` is running on a non-Fx thread, hence it is running concurrently with `Preloader start()`

Comment: Alright, firtst of all I want thank you, jns, for your replay, but For example I have a preloader stage as Singleton (static instance with private constructor) and if I try to invoke MyPreloaderStage.getInstance in init of Preloader it gives me a RuntimeException(( I just want to keep alive a transition animation in Preloader's stage and load a primary (application stage) Maybe it's not possible..

Comment: Could you post the complete code of the involved classes, otherwise it's really hard to say what's not working.

Comment: `Preloader init()` is not running on the `JavaFX Application Thread`, hence the RuntimeException when you call `LoaderFrame.getInstance()`: **Stage objects must be constructed and modified on the JavaFX Application Thread.**. As the Preloader already has a Stage there is no need to construct a new one. You only need to create a root component for the existing stage. (If you use `@FXML` annotations in the corresponding controller, you won't have to use all the `lookup` statements.)