# JavaFX Preloader never called from main

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

My IDE is IntelliJ. I tried [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm) document to learn preloader but for some reason preloader never gets called from my main class, or even its methods get called.

**So here is my main class:**

```
public class LongInitApp extends Application {
Stage stage;
BooleanProperty ready = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
private void longStart() {
    //simulate long init in background
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            int max = 10;
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                notifyPreloader(new ProgressNotification(((double) i)/max));
            }
            ready.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);

            notifyPreloader(new StateChangeNotification(
                StateChangeNotification.Type.BEFORE_START));
           return null;
        }};
    new Thread(task).start();
}

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    launch(args);
  }

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    longStart();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Label("Application started"),400, 400));
    ready.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
        public void changed(
            ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(t1)) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            stage.show();
                        }});}}});;}}
```

**And my preloader class:**

```
public class LongAppInitPreloader extends Preloader {
ProgressBar bar;
Stage stage;
boolean noLoadingProgress = true;

private Scene createPreloaderScene() {
    bar = new ProgressBar(0);
    BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
    p.setCenter(bar);
    return new Scene(p, 300, 150);
}

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    this.stage = stage;
    stage.setScene(createPreloaderScene());
    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void handleProgressNotification(ProgressNotification pn) {
    if (pn.getProgress() != 1.0 || !noLoadingProgress) {
      bar.setProgress(pn.getProgress()/2);
      if (pn.getProgress() > 0) {
          noLoadingProgress = false;
      }
    }
}

@Override
public void handleStateChangeNotification(StateChangeNotification evt) {
    //ignore, hide after application signals it is ready
}

@Override
public void handleApplicationNotification(PreloaderNotification pn) {
    if (pn instanceof ProgressNotification) {
       double v = ((ProgressNotification) pn).getProgress();
       if (!noLoadingProgress) {           
           v = 0.5 + v/2;
       }
       bar.setProgress(v);            
    } else if (pn instanceof StateChangeNotification) {
        stage.hide();
    }
}  
 }
```

You can check this http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm document too. This codes belong to example 9-11 and 9-12.

Comment: Where are you loading the `Preloader`? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551620/javafx-preloader-thread/43554718#43554718

Comment: How are you executing the application? It needs to be packaged with the preloader specified (or use non-public API classes for launching, as in the question linked above). Simply executing the main class here won't cause the preloader to be loaded.

Comment: I thought i would be launching it when i use notifyPreloader method.
Do i have to launch it like  
"LauncherImpl.launchApplication(App.class, TestPreloader.class, args);" ?

Comment: So I've added the LauncherImpl method to my LongInitApp class. It opens but immediatly closes. And i wanted to use this preloader for a csv reader program that i wrote when its parsing it should be seen as loading. I believe i dont understand how Preloaders work. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: How are you anticipating deploying this application? Are you going to deploy it via web start? Or are you just going to create a jar file or self-contained application bundle? If you are not going to use web start, I would probably not bother with a preloader at all: just launch a task in a background thread, show a window, and when the task completes show the main window and hide the original window. I think the preloader mechanism is really there to assist when the real application takes a long time to download over a network connection: there's no need for that complexity in a desktop app.

Comment: Well, i think you're right James_D. I will use a simple thread instead of preloader. But i still want to learn it:D Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the preloader class to the application when it launches. A "quick and dirty" way to do this is to use the non-public API class `com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl`. Note that this class is not guaranteed to be available in future releases of JavaFX, and so you should use this for quick testing only (if at all). Use the following main method in your `LongInitApp` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LongInitApp.class, LongAppInitPreloader.class, args);
}
```

The "official" way to include a preloader is by specifying it as part of the JavaFX deployment process. Full documentation of the deployment process is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/, but a minimal approach is as follows.

1. Compile the application (your IDE will typically do this when you save anyway)
2. From the command line, run the `javapackager` tool with the `createjar` command:

   ```
   javapackager -createjar -outfile myapp.jar -appclass my.package.LongInitApp \
     -preloader my.package.LongAppInitPreloader -srcdir dir
   ```

   where `my.package` is the package containing your application and preloader classes (these can be in different packages) and `dir` is the root of the directory structure containing all your classes (e.g. if `my.package` really were your package name, then `dir` would have a sub-directory `my`, which would have a subdirectory `package`, which would contain the `.class` files).

   This will generate a `myapp.jar` file which is executable and aware of your preloader, so you can then execute it with `java -jar myapp.jar`. If you're interested, you can extract the generated manifest from the jar file and see what's in it with `jar xf myapp.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (and then view the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`). (In brief, what this does is declare the main class to be an internal class designed to launch a JavaFX application. The manifest file contains properties specifying the JavaFX application class (`LongInitApp` in your case) and the preloader class, if one exists. The internal class that launches the application retrieves these properties and its main method basically launches the application you have defined, using the preloader if it's there.)

   Note your application class `LongInitApp` does not need (and probably **should not have**) a `main` method if you use this approach.

Most IDEs have some form of support for this. E.g. if you use Eclipse with the E(fx)clipse plugin, and create a JavaFX project, it will generate a `build.fxbuild` file for you. Double-clicking that file will open a visual editor where you can set the properties defined in the `javapackager` command above. Clicking on "Generate ant build.xml and run" will then create the jar file.

Unless you need the specific functionality that a preloader provides, above and beyond that which you can easily program yourself, it may not be worth the effort of going through this. Specifically, a preloader is particularly useful if you are deploying your application via Java Web Start, and the download of the main jar file will take a long time. The preloader can be shown while that is occurring. If you are using a standalone application (or self-contained application package), then you can pretty easily create the "preloader" functionality yourself.

For example, unless I were using Java Web Start and the main jar file were large, I would probably refactor your example code by making the "preloader" just a regular old class:

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty ;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LongAppInitPreloader {
    private ProgressBar bar;

    private Stage stage;

    public LongAppInitPreloader() {
        this.stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(createPreloaderScene());
    }

    private Scene createPreloaderScene() {
        bar = new ProgressBar(0);
        BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
        p.setCenter(bar);
        return new Scene(p, 300, 150);
    }

    public void show() {
        stage.show();
    }

    public void hide() {
        stage.hide();
    }

    public DoubleProperty progressProperty() {
        return bar.progressProperty();
    }
}
```

and then your application class can just use a task and update its progress:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LongInitApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Task<Void> task = createLongStartTask();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Label("Application started"), 400, 400));

        LongAppInitPreloader preloader = new LongAppInitPreloader();
        preloader.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            stage.show();
            preloader.hide();
        });
        preloader.show();

        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    private Task<Void> createLongStartTask() {
        // simulate long init in background
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                int max = 10;
                for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    updateProgress(i, max);
                }

                return null;
            }
        };
        return task ;
    }

    // just here so I can run directly from Eclipse:
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but after your comment i changed my mind my application is far too simple for preloader. So, I tried thread.start() method but it still waits for the first application to continue. Then i tried as below:

Comment: I tried Platform.runlater to run a simpleLoader class, before a for loop and after the loop. Loop is just there to simulate a progress. What i want is when its in the for loop sp(simpleLoader) should be seen as loading animation. But instead it opens the sp but not loads any nodes inside (it contains a bar and label) and closes after the for loop. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you running the "simple loader" on the Fx Application Thread? That will prevent the UI from updating until it is finished.

Comment: @Jeredriq The last part of my question shows exactly how to do this without using a preloader. Did you run that? Why not do it that way?

Comment: I called it with a thread but now im trying your method with Task.
Btw im calling a class in thread and sending alerts on errors but when i call it from the thread alerts doesnt show up.
What do you advice?

Comment: Did the example I posted work when you tried to run it? I don't understand what you mean by "I'm calling a class in thread": you call methods, not classes. Are you trying to show alerts using either `Alert` or `Stage`? If so, are you doing that part back on the FX Application Thread? If you can't get it to work you should probably post a new question.

Comment: your code worked perfectly man,  After i declared my task i used task.setOnSucceeded for the alerts
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Main method in LongInitApp class

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: I added it nothing has changed.